# How to prevent user from picking an option more than once

Tags: c++

I have wrote a very very simple quiz c++ program (who wants to be a millionaire) which reads the questions from the file,
I would like to include a special help option which will skip the answer when used. The problem is that I do not want the user to use that option more than once, how can I do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a[15]; //Array which will take answers
    string print, print2; //Strings for printing questions
    ifstream answers("q&a.txt");
    cout << "Welcome to who wants to be a millionaire\n";
    while (answers) //Read questions from the file
    {
        getline(answers, print);
        auto position = print.find( "01." );
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1 );
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Blackburn Losers\nB. Blackburn Rovers\nC. Blackburn Lovers\nD. BlackburnWanderers\n";
        }
        cin >> a[0];
        if (a[0] == "b") //If correct, proceed to next question
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("02.");
        }
        //If the answer is wrong, terminate the program
        if (a[0] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Fridge\nB. Bank\nC. Market\nD. Shoe\n";
        }
        cin >> a[1];
        if (a[1] == "b")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("03");
        }
        if (a[1] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Bassey\nB. Kwesi\nC. Abiodun\nD. Ejima\n";
        }
        cin >> a[2];
        if (a[2] == "b")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("04.");
        }
        if (a[2] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Inferno\nB. Domino\nC. Stiletto\nD. Tornado\n";
        }
        cin >> a[3];
        if (a[3] == "a")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("05.");
        }
        if (a[3] != "a")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Marry a wife\nB. Bury a dead parent\nC. Have thanksgiving in church\nD. Accept gifts or favour in kind\n";
        }
        cin >> a[4];
        if (a[4] == "d")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("06.");
        }
        if (a[4] != "d")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Tenacity\nB. Verifiability\nC. Hereditary\nD. Validation\n";
        }
        cin >> a[5];
        if (a[5] == "c")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("07.");
        }
        if (a[5] != "c")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Paris\nB. Copenhagen\nC. New York\nD. Madrid\n";
        }
        cin >> a[6];
        if (a[6] == "a")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("08");
        }
        if (a[6] != "a")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 =  print.substr(position +1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Mumbai\nB. Beijing\nC. Rio de Janeiro\nD. Seville\n";
        }
        cin >> a[7];
        if (a[7] == "b")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("09");
        }
        if (a[7] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. A speed equal to that of sound\nB. A speed greater than that of sound\nC. A speed equal to that of light\nD. A speed greater than that of light\n";
        }
        cin >> a[8];
        if (a[8] == "b")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("10.");
        }
        if (a[8] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Nephrons\nB. Nerves\nC. Ligaments\nD. Stitches\n";
        }
        cin >> a[9];
        if (a[9] == "c")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("11.");
        }
        if (a[9] != "c")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Swimmer\nB. Referee\nC. Football Fan\nD. Judoka\n";
        }
        cin >> a[10];
        if (a[10] == "b")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("12.");
        }
        if (a[10] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. France\nB. United States\nC. Germany\nD. India\n";
        }
        cin >> a[11];
        if (a[11] == "c")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("13.");
        }
        if (a[11] != "c")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Clint Eastwood\nB. Oliver Stone\nC. Peter Jackson\nD. Morgan Freeman\n";
        }
        cin >> a[12];
        if (a[12] == "a")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("14.");
        }
        if (a[12] != "a")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Lebanon\nB. Columbia\nC. Japan\nD. Eritrea\n";
        }
        cin >> a[13];
        if (a[13] == "b")
        {
            getline(answers, print);
            position = print.find("15.");
        }
        if (a[13] != "b")
        {
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (position <= print.size())
        {
            print2 = print.substr(position + 1);
            cout << print2 << endl << "A. Literature\nB. Economics\nC. Peace\nD. Medicine\n";
            cin >> a[14];
        }
        if (a[14] == "c")
        {
            cout << "Congratulations!\nYou won a million dollars!\n";
            break;
        }
        if (a[14] != "c")
            cerr << "We are sorry, you are wrong!\n";
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Questions:

```
   01. Which of these is the name of a British Football Club?
   02. An establishment where money can be deposited or withdrawn is       called what?
   03 Name given to a boy born on Sunday in Ghana is what?
   04. Which of the following refer to the word fire?
   05. According to the constitution a public officer is not allowed to do which of these?
   06. The process by which genetic traits are transmitted from parents        to offspring is called what?
   07. Roland Garros stadium is in which city?
   08. Where is Tiananmen Square?
   09. The word supersonic denotes which of these?
   10. Which of these holds bones together at the joints of the body?
   11. Linus Mbah achieved fame in Nigerian sporting circles as what?
   12. DAX refers to the stock market of which country?
   13. Who won the Academy Award for directing the movie ‘Million    Dollar Baby’?
   14. In which country is the Galeras Volcano?
   15. Professor Maathai Wangari won the Nobel Prize for which of these?
```

Answers:

```
   1 (B)
   2 (B)
   3 (B)
   4 (A)
   5 (D)
   6 (C)
   7 (A)
   8 (B)
   9 (B)
   10 (C)
   11 (B)
   12 (C)
   13 (A)
   14 (B)
   I15 (C)
```

Comment: Using the debugger yourself to find out what's the actual problem is probably way more efficient than asking other people here doing that for you.

Comment: Answers for the questions should also be loaded file a file...

Comment: You should understand that root of your problem is in bad structure of code. One function for everything - very bad approach. Consider moving parts of code to small functions. After that you will see you code better and, perhaps, you will answer your questions without help

Comment: I didn't know how clever you are, I asked, if you don't want to help, please stay away!

Comment: @TecHummer _"The problem is that I do not want the user to use that option more than once, how can I do that."_ Remember users former choíces e.g. in a `std::vector` or such. Check if it can be found already before proving it's valid and add to the vector member.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 _"Spend the time to watch some youtube videos, it will do you a world of good! "_ Puke! Nope that's certainly not the way to learn programming languages. Use text books and textual form language references. Videos are the worst source I could think learning from.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry for the knee-jerk reaction - I just saw a wall of code and read the question, incorrectly, as "what went wrong?," and not, "What do I have to add to do x?" 100% agreed with you that youtube is NOT the place to learn how to code, but I've found a *few* useful tutorials on how to debug... My original comment was certainly off topic!

Comment: In English, sentences are separated by periods ("full stops"), not commas. You can edit your post.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a boolean called "usedHelp", and initialize it as 'false'. Test for it on each question, ie:

```
if (a[0] == "?" && (!usedHelp) ) // This means the user pressed the 'help' key (in this case, a question mark  '?') and they haven't already used it.
{
    usedHelp = true; // Now set the 'úsedHelp' variable to 'true'. The next time a user presses '?', it will skip a similar if statement
    getline(answers, print);
    position = print.find("02.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to compact your "sausage" code into a loop. The only thing that is different is the possible answers, and also which of them is the correct one. I suggest you put that in the file too, so the file looks something like this:

```
Which of these is the name of a British Football Club?
Blackburn Rovers
Blackburn Losers
Blackburn Lovers
Blackburn Wanderers
An establishment where money can be deposited or withdrawn is called what?
Bank
Fridge
Market
Shoe
...
```

Every challenge takes 5 lines of text, first the question, then the correct answer, then 3 incorrect answers. You read five consecutive lines (no need to `find` them in a string), then print the question (first line), then add the three incorrect answers into some `vector<string>`, then [shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/shuffle/) that `vector`, then insert the correct answer into a random place [0-3], but remember which is it. Get the answer from the user and compare with what you remembered.

Then repeat the loop. This will make a very elegant solution that you can expand upon. You want the ability for the user to skip one answer? No problem, introduce one `bool` flag that is `false` at first but turns to `true` once the user uses the ability. When the user asks to skip the answer first check for this flag, to see if users already spent this ability.

Because you'll be using loop this code will be added only once. That's good. If you realize you should change the code you'll be changing it at only one place, and not in 20. That's awesome.